# SKPhysicsBody appears too big

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have an `SKSpriteNode` of an airplane. Here is image (300px x 83px):

[image: An airplane]

The image is named as `p40@2x.png` in my Xcode project.

Now I'm adding a physics body to the airplane:

```
CGFloat offsetX = self.size.width * self.anchorPoint.x;
CGFloat offsetY = self.size.height * self.anchorPoint.y;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 24 - offsetX, 124 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 24 - offsetX, 47 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 339 - offsetX, 1 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 401 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 452 - offsetX, 52 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 411 - offsetX, 78 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 295 - offsetX, 78 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 268 - offsetX, 93 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 95 - offsetX, 78 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 62 - offsetX, 124 - offsetY);

CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
```

`CGPath` is generated by [SKPhysicsBody Path Generator](http://dazchong.com/spritekit/)

To debug the airplane's physics body I've added an `SKShapeNode` with the same `CGPath` as for physics body:

```
SKShapeNode *shape = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
shape.path = path;
shape.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
[self addChild:shape];
```

Here is the result:

[image: result]

Am I doing something wrong?

**PS:** Notices an interesting thing. If I specify `CGPath` as follows:

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 24/3.0 - offsetX, 124/3.0 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 24/3.0 - offsetX, 47/3.0 - offsetY);
```

the shape fits the airplane well!

Comment: Did you create the shape with the generator using the @2x version of the image? Try using the "@2x" image and make sure the Retina checkbox is set. In general try different variations to see what it looks like on Retina and non Retina devices. Though the shape doesn't look like it's 2x scaled, more like 3x or 4x.

Comment: I'm using the image I've attached. The same image goes to Xcode project. The shape looks like 3x scaled.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be relevant, but, your defined shape is `concave`. The docs say it must be `convex`. If you recreate your path with a convex shape, does that help?

[image]

Examples: [Convex and Concave polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons)

Comment: Could you link the doc where it says that? I'm pretty sure that it said you COULD use concave, but that you will get laggy gameplay

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe my mistake. From everything I've read it is that you can't create concave SKPhysicsBodies, but, you can join convex bodies together to create a body that looks concave, but is made up of convex shapes. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithPolygonFromPath:). Where did you read about "..get laggy gameplay.."?

Comment: Well, the laggy part was my own bit since, like you said, it takes more processing speed, as you would need to use more complex convex chapes.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the original dimensions (320 x 480) or in case of iPhone5+ (320 x 568). @2x/@4x images are only to provide higher resolution images for retina devices. But for backward compatibility reasons all devices still share the same coordinate system.

So your path should be something like:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"jPfsF.png"];

CGFloat offsetX = sprite.frame.size.width * sprite.anchorPoint.x;
CGFloat offsetY = sprite.frame.size.height * sprite.anchorPoint.y;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 18 - offsetX, 41 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 31 - offsetX, 25 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 91 - offsetX, 31 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 95 - offsetX, 24 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 136 - offsetX, 26 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 148 - offsetX, 18 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 133 - offsetX, 2 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 75 - offsetX, 1 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 9 - offsetX, 16 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 11 - offsetX, 40 - offsetY);

CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you need to calculate the points, not the pixels. If you have an @1x image, then it will have the same size in points and pixels. For @2x you will have the same number of points, but double number of pixels and so on for @3x...